STM32 - failed to enable SWV configuration, failed to execute MI Command
I am working on a STM32 board and I am configuring the SWD traces. I am following some tutorials to configure it, however I have this error message when I debug. I tried some solutions found online (in this forum and the stm electronics one) but it's not working. I tried to open a new project but I've got the same mistake.
Here is the message of error I got
Here is the function that I have to communicate/print
Here is my main to print "hello" in an infinite loop
So I configured the debug this way 
I am joining the part below
I want to be able to press "Start Traces" and that it prints my message.
Does anyone have any idea ?
Thank you

Place your _write function outside of the main function. Do not declare functions within other. E.g :
function1 {
...
}
function2 {
...
}
And not :
function1 {
...
function2 {
...
}
}

@Issylin Hello, I did it but i received the same error message...

Try checking the box "ST-Link SN", then Scan and select your device manually, then launch your debug session. If it still doesn't work, can you edit your post and detail all steps you made, i.e. 1. you built, 2. you clicked on whatever icon, 3. did it open the debug session interface ? Have you seen the ST-Link GDB Server starting (you should have a list of several params written in the log panel). Did you receive the error message after this step ? If yes, that must be a CubeProgrammer issue. Also, what version of CubeIDE are you using, and on what OS (I assume Windows ?)

Hello, thank you for your help, i don't have the error message anymore but i still have weird characters in my SWM ITM Data Console.

I work with the 1.15.1 version of STM32CubeIDE and my OS is, indeed, Windows. I change the debug configuration as you said. In my .ioc, i put "Trace Asynchronous SW" in SYS for the Debug and i put 64 MHz for the clock of SW since the clock of the System is 64MHz in the clock configuration. It said that it was downloaded successfully but instead of having a lot of "hello", i have this kind of characters:xÅ???
å?Øx

To your main issue, I'll post an answer based on my previous comment. For the second issue you have, you should check for similar issues online and if you didn't find the root cause, create another post with all information + your full code, including clock init (not a picture of your code)

By checking the box "ST-Link SN", then Scan and select your device manually, you can prevent CubeIDE to launch a ST-Link GDB Server session with the wrong assumption on the target to be used. This behavior can sometimes happen if you have several devices connected to your computer, including several other ST Links with different versions (v2/v3).
Side note for your code, functions shouldn't be implemented within other functions in C. You should implement them as follows :
function1
{
    ...
}

function2
{
    ...
}

And not :
function1
{
    ...
    function2
    {
        ...
    }
} 


Hello @Issylin, i tried to re-run my program, but now i have the same error as the screen of my first post, i don't understand because i didn't change anything, and the last time i didn't have that error.

the message error appears after the ST-Link GDB Server have started because I have a list of several params written in the console, so it is a CubeProgrammer issue as you mentionned before you think ?

@Saramaz it may sound crazy, but most of the times backend issue from CubeProgrammer because the connection between CubeProg & your board failed. Have you tried unplugging and replugging the board from the computer ? Btw, what board are you using ?

Hello @Issylin, Yes i try to unplug and plug again but the same issue remains. I am using a STM32WB5MM DK.
